# Как вернуть объект со свойствами в обратном порядке?

Tags: php

есть ли для объектов функция потипу `array_reverse` Есть такой объект

```
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[2666]
      public '@attributes' => 
        array (size=2)
          'id' => string '3451' (length=4)
          'available' => string 'true' (length=4)
      public 'url' => string 'http://miliydom.com.ua//single.php?id=3451' (length=42)
      public 'vendorCode' => string '№0050-55' (length=10)
      public 'price' => string '780' (length=3)
      public 'delivery' => string 'true' (length=4)
      public 'currencyId' => string 'UAH' (length=3)
      public 'country_of_origin' => string 'Украина' (length=14)
      public 'categoryId' => string '53' (length=2)
      public 'name' => string 'Парка "Значки"' (length=25)
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[112]
      public '@attributes' => 
        array (size=2)
          'id' => string '3450' (length=4)
          'available' => string 'true' (length=4)
      public 'url' => string 'http://miliydom.com.ua//single.php?id=3450' (length=42)
      public 'vendorCode' => string '№0050-50' (length=10)
      public 'price' => string '780' (length=3)
      public 'delivery' => string 'true' (length=4)
      public 'currencyId' => string 'UAH' (length=3)
      public 'country_of_origin' => string 'Украина' (length=14)
      public 'categoryId' => string '53' (length=2)
      public 'name' => string 'Парка "Велосипедики"' (length=37)
```

мне через `foreach` перебрать их в обратном порядке как это возможно ?

Comment: А каким образом вы их получаете в "прямом" порядке?

Comment: а цикл `for` уже отменили, да?

Comment: Как костыль могу предложить перебрать в прямом порядке, при переборе записывать объект в массив, а потом получить массив в обратном порядке.  Интересно для какой задачи это может понадобиться?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а как в for это сделать? я так на выстрел foreach написал

Comment: @rjhdby в xml документе которые не мой я лишь используя его пытаюсь записать даные в базу

Comment: Вы не поняли. Каким образом вы В СВОЕМ КОДЕ получаете "прямой" порядок? То, что я вижу в вопросе - это очень похоже на var_dump(), а не на какую-то логику.

Comment: @heff пишите ответ это конечно жестко но пришлось использовать ваш вариант:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если эти объекты попадают к вам AS IS, и вам надо, зачем-то, получить список его публичных свойств, то имеет смысл воспользоваться [Reflection](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.reflection.php).

```
class Foo{
    public $a=10;
    public $b="test";
};

$foo = new Foo();
$reflect = new ReflectionClass($foo);
$props   = $reflect->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC);

foreach ($props as $prop) {
    $name = $prop->getName();
    $array[$name] = $foo->$name;
}
```

И дальше используйте этот массив в любом порядке.

Answer (score 0):

Объект simplexml вполне адекватно транслируется в обычный массив штатными методами:

```
$xml = new SimpleXmlElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><foo bar="1"><x>3</x><a>1</a><b>2</b></foo>');
$arr = (array) $xml;
ksort($arr);
var_dump($xml, $arr);
```

Вместо приведения к массиву можно воспользоваться функцией `get_object_vars`, эффект в целом тот же.

Отдельный вопрос в том, почему вообще понадобилось как-то выводить изначальный XML. Обычно разработчик знает, какие поля в этом XML есть и выводит нужные ему в нужных местах нормальным обращением по имени свойства.

Comment: xml не мой я просто на его основе пытаюсь записать даный в базу

Comment: "Объект simplexml вполне адекватно транслируется в обычный массив штатными методами" А как же опп :)

Comment: Тогда нафига вам понадобился вообще какой-то порядок? Обращайтесь к конкретным необходимым полям и формируйте свою запись в базу. А если один элемент в XML вам попадётся с другим порядком полей? Весь процесс порушится или в базу вообще запишете не то? А ооп ради ооп не имеет смысла.